# Rails Jruby LoadError: no such file to load , when using Java Class in config.after_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I am using jruby and I need to launch some java code after I initialized something. Below is the code that I need to launch in application.rb. I have the proper classes and libraries imported.

```
config.after_initialize do
  ihp = IPHistoryProcessor.new("/home/ubuntu/jruby/logs/inputFiles/")
end
```

However I get the following error

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- /home/ubuntu/jruby/jruby_try_4/config/environment 
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
block in require at /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247
........
```

I can call the other built in ruby classes but not this java class that I made. I have no idea where the problem could begin. Most indications from other posts I see suggest it is a Passenger problem but I am using Puma for the server. Any help to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to tell JRuby where to look for your Java `.class` ... otherwise it does not know anything about Rails (there's no convention for auto-loading .class files from a location such as *lib*) ... try :

```
$CLASSPATH << 'lib/java' # set this early e.g. in boot.rb
```

or whereverer `IPHistoryProcessor.class` is (including the pkg dir structure)